# Renaming Files With Same Name, Different Extension in Linux:

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have a listing of files with the same name, but different file extensions:

```
name.a
name.b
name.c
...
name.z
```

and want to rename them to:

```
newname.a
newname.b
newname.c
...
newname.z
```

How could I do this rename operation in one bash command?

Comment: Why the downvote? Seems like a valid question to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use parameter expansion:

```
for f in name.*; do 
    ext="${f##*.}" 
    mv "$f" "newname.$ext"
done
```

There is an excellent write-up about it [here](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide/Parameters#Parameter_Expansion)

Comment: +1: This works wonderfully, though I would like to find a built-in solution that works like the one that @anubhava mentioned.

Comment: You can use this as a one-liner too:
`for f in name.*;do ext="${f##*.}"; mv "$f" "newname.$ext"; done`

Comment: I ended up making an alias for this command as I could not get @anubhava's solution to work. Thank you very much.

Comment: This doesn't work if there is a file without extension, for example `name`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `rename` utility:

```
rename 's/^name\./newname./' name.*
```

Comment: This looks great and I am surprised I have not heard of `rename` before. (Guess my Google searches were too particular; all I saw was the `mv` command.) Thank you. I'll test it out and then I'll be back to accept this answer.

Comment: Hm. I tried this with the files I had in mind and it did not work, so I made two files, `name.a` and `name.b` and tested the command exactly as you wrote it. It does not rename the files. My regex is a bit rusty. Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: I did the same and tested this exact command and got files renamed. Result was `newname.a` and `newname.b`

Comment: Very strange. It does not work for me. Thank you all the same.

Comment: Yes really weird. Can you do `type rename` and see what it shows. Also try: `rename 's/name\./newname./' name.*`

Comment: `type` is not found and I do not have privileges to install new packages on this machine. That command also does nothing.

Comment: There are many variations of the `rename` command, if you're using the one that comes with the `perl` packages, this should work. If not it won't. Can easily check this by looking at the man page.

Comment: Ah. Yes. That seems to be the problem. While I can not use this solution, it does appear to be the most elegant. Thank you.